# What is the most appropriate way to assign and test a variable in an if statement?

Tags: c

Of the following, which is the preferred way of doing things, and why? Are there any specific situations in which it makes any difference, **assuming that the function bar() does not take the value zero at any time**?

Case 1: Test the truth value of both conditions

```
if ((foo = bar()) && foo < 0)
    error();
```

Case 2: Test only the assigned variable

```
if ((foo = bar()) < 0)
    error();
```

Comment: For those who find this and are using Perl, the idiom is `foo = bar() or error();`. This can also be done in C, but it is not common practise and may confuse: `(foo = bar()) || error();` -- Perl's assignment has higher precedence than `||`, but in C it is the reverse.

Comment: @PhilH It is generally considered bad style to include conditional side effects as the right operand of a boolean operation (MISRA-C 12.4). And your code will only work if error() returns something. So don't attempt that in C.

Comment: Good point on the return requirement; I suppose in Perl there is no such checking and error() will always run.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The preferred way is to separate them:

```
foo = bar();
if (foo < 0)
    error();
```

Edit: This is better way for both readability and avoiding bugs, such as in your first case:

```
if (foo = bar() && foo < 0)
    error();
```

That should probably be:

```
if ((foo = bar()) && foo < 0)
    error();
```

Comment: Has this way any better performance? Or is it the preferred just for better readability?

Comment: While I can't tell you if there is a difference in any compiler, C coder should not care about that. This is better way for both readability and avoiding bugs. (as in OP first case)

Comment: There should be absolutely no difference in performance. In either case, the machine code will be: excute bar(), store the result temporarily somewhere, then store it in foo, then branch if foo is less than zero.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is plain wrong. Because of precedence rules, you get:

```
if (foo = (bar() && foo < 0))
    error();
```

which is usually not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The first example works, but if someone tries to change `<` to `<=` or `>=`, it'll explode: for `bar` returning 0, it will test the first part of the and statement and will consider it false, aborting the second check, which should be true.

Also, your first example does not do what it supposed to do: operator precedence of `=` is less than `&&`, so you get assignment of result of &&-operation to `foo`

So I'd prefer the second example.

Answer (score 0):

In most situations that shouldn't matter. Your first case has some redundancy so I'd prefer the second suggestion for shortness.

There are some situations where this approach isn't good enough, specifically in a multi-threaded environment where your variable is a shared asset (set & test operation is very common there). In this case the access to the variable needs to be properly guarded (i.e. by locking) to avoid races and data corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers if not all will issue a warning if you attempt to do assignment within a conditional extra parenthesis.

But in most cases, I'd argue that its less readable to compound statements like that, while it make sense in say Ruby it is just not that common in C. Without a rationale that would never pass code review IMO.